# How to use separate CMake targets for host application and any of the used libraries?

Tags: c++, cmake

When I'm using CMake and library which also uses CMake, I add the library directory in my CMake project to allow building the library alongside my project. For example:

```
 # add SFML library dependencies
 add_subdirectory("third_party/lib/SFML")
 include_directories("third_party/lib/SFML/include")
 target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} sfml-system sfml-window sfml-graphics)
```

Then CMake automatically matches project *Debug* builds to use library *Debug* build, and project *Release* builds to use library *Release* build. In some cases it is useful build targets to be controlled separately for the main project and every one of the libraries used by it. For example, if I'm not interested in debugging inside the library code I will want to build in *Debug* mode only my code and to link it against *Release* version of the library, because I don't want to sacrifice additional performance. In other cases maybe I want to debug only inside one of the used libraries, if I have suspicious for bug inside it, but again for performance reasons I want to link release versions for all other libraries. Is it possible and what is the best way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With both imported targets and dependent targets from the same build tree, you will always get the behavior you described, that each configuration uses its own matching build of the library. Messing with this means fiddling with CMake's internals, so I'd advise against it.

If you want to link against a specific version of the library, the most robust way is to use [`find_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html). Note that this will only work if the library dependency is already available in its binary form at configure time. That is, you can no longer build the dependency as part of the dependent project.

If that is not an option, consider using [`ExternalProject_Add`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html) to build the dependency and specify the location of the dependency binary manually.

All in all, your current approach is the most convenient one, so only change this if performance of the dependency's debug build is a real problem. Also note that while mixing debug and release builds is mostly fine for C libraries, it can easily break for C++ libraries, especially if you have standard library types on the interfaces.